# How can I bypass parent's attributeset to child in android

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I am creating compond view with imageView + TextView as ImageTextView as follow in xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<Button android:id="@+id/btnView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/txtView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

in usage, I want to use ImageTextView as follow:

```
<com.mypkg.MyClass.ImageTextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="text for textView"   //used for textview
        android:background="@drawable/background.png"  //used for image view
/>
```

in imageTextViewConstructor, I want to bypass textSize, text, textColor and all textView's attributes to child txtView without layoutParams as following logic, how can I filter AttributeSet in java code.

```
public ImageTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
         //------------------------------
        // AttributeSet filteredAttrs= filterAttributeSet(attrs);
        //I want to remove layoutparams and background from parent attributeset
        //------------------------------
       TextView mtxtView=(TextView)findViewByid(R.id.txtView);
        mtxtView=new TextView(this,filteredAttrs);
    }
```

Comment: It's not currently possible to modify or safely wrap AttributeSet, but you could manually change the attributes after construction.

Also, why are you using findViewById() in your ImageTextView constructor? It will always return null.

Comment: I m not sure am I right, but I think findViewById() can be used in constructor  after super constructor call, and it works for me, thanks anyway. My idea is to specify both attribute for textview and imageview within ImageTextView scope linearly. I feel it's really productive and extensible rather than constructing layout manually with textview and imageview and assigning attributes seprately.

Answer (score -1):

`TextView` by itself can contain a `Drawable` on top, bottom, left (start) and/or right (end).

```
<TextView
  ...
  android:drawablePadding="4dp"
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_drawable"/>
```

More on this topic here: http://antonioleiva.com/textview_power_drawables/

Comment: Thanks, actually my problem is not specifying attribute for textView, but specifying child view's attributes from parentView dynamically. In my custom control, I can't access textview directly within xml, please focus on this usage. `<com.mypkg.MyClass.ImageTextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="text for textView"   //used for textview
        android:background="@drawable/background.png"  //used for image view
/>`